# Is it possible to enable usb debug without touch screen?

Tags: usb-debugging, broken-screen

I have a samsung i9100 phone. The screen is broken. Usb debug mode is not enabled. So is it possible to enable usb debug in such situation? I don't want to replace the screen now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be rooted and have ROM with sqlite3 support e.g., Cyanogemod. If yes, you can try updating the settings files manually via entering adb shell:

```
su
sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
update global set value='1' where name='adb_enabled';
update global set value='1' where name='development_settings_enabled';
exit
reboot
```

caveat: if you're rooted but have never invoked su via adb, then the system will ask for granting permissions to adb client which of course is displayed on screen and, depending on your superuser app defaults, will be automatically granted or rejected since the screen is broken.

An existing XDA thread suggests a manual push/pull method [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/help/broken-digitizer-to-enable-usb-t2206706/page2).

Comment: I'm a little at a loss here: "updating the settings files manually via entering adb shell" requires *USB debugging* to be enabled already, so how shall that work? Following your link, it seems you've missed to mention a crucial requirement: installing a custom recovery which has USB debugging enabled. Could that be?

Comment: I guess you can install a custom recovery...

Comment: Precisely. That's why I began by saying that you need to be **rooted** which means that one has already installed custom recovery. This question has been marked duplicate so I guess it won't get much attention if you get stuck. I suggest looking into the linked question. Hope it helps.