# Grant access to ADB on broken screen

Tags: usb-debugging, broken-screen

My phone screen is completely broken and good thing is that its debugging mode is on and I can access my phone screen using Vysor on a PC. But I have another PC, and when I try to access my phone with that system, I have to grant access with the OK button, but I can't do that.

How can I access my phone screen on a different PC or grant debugging?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to enable usb debug without touch screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64361/is-it-possible-to-enable-usb-debug-without-touch-screen)

Comment: I don't think this is *quite* a duplicate, because that question is about turning on debugging in the first place, while this question is about allowing access from a new PC.

Answer (score 1):

This guide assumes that USB debugging was enabled on your device before you broke it. You can enable USB debugging via a custom recovery, such as twrp, using:

```
adb shell
echo "persist.service.adb.enable=1" >>/system/build.prop
echo "persist.service.debuggable=1" >>/system/build.prop
echo "persist.sys.usb.config=mass_storage,adb" >>/system/build.prop"
reboot
```

This method was used to bypass the secure USB prompt on a Galaxy SII with a shattered screen. I think it may work on another device too...

For this to work, you need another device running Android 4.4.2 or above with USB debugging enabled and the same computer authorised from that device. i.e. connect that device to your computer and press "OK" on the authorisation prompt that appears on screen for secure USB debugging. Let us call this device the *authorised device*.

**adb_keys** is the file we need from the authorised device which is located in `/data/misc/adb/`
Normally you must be rooted to take the adb_keys file from the device using **Root explorer** or ES File Explorer,  but let's assume that the authorised device is unrooted. You don't need to root it. However, if your authorised device is rooted then simply copy the *adb_keys* file on your computer and jump directly to **Step 3**.

Steps:

1. Connect the *authorised device* to your computer using USB (debugging enabled) and open a command prompt with administrator privileges (**Minimal ADB & Fastboot** is perfect here).
2. To get the *adb_keys* file, use this command:

   adb pull /data/misc/adb/adb_keys /adb_keys

For example:

```
adb pull /data/misc/adb/adb_keys c:/adb_keys
```

The above command will save the *adb_keys* file to the root of your C: drive. You can change the destination folder to your liking.

Now the job of the authorised device is done. You can disconnect it and disable USB debugging.

3. Once you get a copy of *adb_keys*, reboot the phone with the broken screen into recovery.
4. Now connect the broken phone to the computer using USB.
5. We need to copy the *adb_keys* file to the broken device. Use the command below:

   adb push  /data/misc/adb

For example:

```
adb push c:/adb_keys /data/misc/adb
```

6. After the file is copied, reboot your device using `adb reboot` et voila! You can now use adb shell on that computer.

Furthermore, if you want to have full control over your device even with a broken screen, the [tool from this thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2786395) lets you use your device through your Windows PC even if your touchscreen doesn't work or you can't see anything. (It requires Java Runtime Environment and Visual C++ redistributable). Or keep using Vysor.

Disclaimer:

The above guide was not made by me and I did not test it myself, I just made minor changes. Just try it and let us know. Good luck.

Original source : [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/help/bypass-secure-usb-debugging-prompt-t2965462/amp/)